# DirectX11 How to load an Obj file

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

How can I load an Object from .obj file without using any 3rd party library? I'm using Visual studio 2013 Windows8!

Comment: By writing the functionality yourself? Seriously, if there are hundreds of libraries for a task and you don't want to utilize any of them, it should be obvious that you have to do it on your own. And since there are lots of libraries, it is likely that it's not an easy task. You have to parse the obj file and possible mtl files, create and fill vertex and index buffers and finally draw all these. Why don't you want to use 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using own std::vector class because std::vector is a little bit slower but you can change the following code for using std::vector

so Here is a CGrowableArray class:
**NOTE: #include < assert.h > and < Windows.h >**

```
template<typename TYPE> class CGrowableArray
{
public:
    CGrowableArray()  { m_pData = NULL; m_nSize = 0; m_nMaxSize = 0; }
    CGrowableArray(const CGrowableArray<TYPE>& a) { for (int i = 0; i < a.m_nSize; i++) Add(a.m_pData[i]); }
    ~CGrowableArray() { RemoveAll(); }

    const TYPE& operator[](int nIndex) const { return GetAt(nIndex); }
    TYPE& operator[](int nIndex) { return GetAt(nIndex); }

    CGrowableArray& operator=(const CGrowableArray<TYPE>& a) { if (this == &a) return *this; RemoveAll(); for (int i = 0; i < a.m_nSize; i++) Add(a.m_pData[i]); return *this; }

    HRESULT SetSize(int nNewMaxSize);
    HRESULT Add(const TYPE& value);
    HRESULT Insert(int nIndex, const TYPE& value);
    HRESULT SetAt(int nIndex, const TYPE& value);
    TYPE&   GetAt(int nIndex) const { assert(nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < m_nSize); return m_pData[nIndex]; }
    int     GetSize() const { return m_nSize; }
    TYPE*   GetData() { return m_pData; }
    bool    Contains(const TYPE& value){ return (-1 != IndexOf(value)); }

    int     IndexOf(const TYPE& value) { return (m_nSize > 0) ? IndexOf(value, 0, m_nSize) : -1; }
    int     IndexOf(const TYPE& value, int iStart) { return IndexOf(value, iStart, m_nSize - iStart); }
    int     IndexOf(const TYPE& value, int nIndex, int nNumElements);

    int     LastIndexOf(const TYPE& value) { return (m_nSize > 0) ? LastIndexOf(value, m_nSize - 1, m_nSize) : -1; }
    int     LastIndexOf(const TYPE& value, int nIndex) { return LastIndexOf(value, nIndex, nIndex + 1); }
    int     LastIndexOf(const TYPE& value, int nIndex, int nNumElements);

    HRESULT Remove(int nIndex);
    void    RemoveAll() { SetSize(0); }
    void    Reset() { m_nSize = 0; }

protected:
    TYPE* m_pData;      // the actual array of data
    int m_nSize;        // # of elements (upperBound - 1)
    int m_nMaxSize;     // max allocated

    HRESULT SetSizeInternal(int nNewMaxSize);  // This version doesn't call ctor or dtor.
};

//----Implementations----
// This version doesn't call ctor or dtor.
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::SetSizeInternal(int nNewMaxSize)
{
    if (nNewMaxSize < 0 || (nNewMaxSize > INT_MAX / sizeof(TYPE)))
    {
        assert(false);
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    if (nNewMaxSize == 0)
    {
        // Shrink to 0 size & cleanup
        if (m_pData)
        {
            free(m_pData);
            m_pData = NULL;
        }

        m_nMaxSize = 0;
        m_nSize = 0;
    }
    else if (m_pData == NULL || nNewMaxSize > m_nMaxSize)
    {
        // Grow array
        int nGrowBy = (m_nMaxSize == 0) ? 16 : m_nMaxSize;

        // Limit nGrowBy to keep m_nMaxSize less than INT_MAX
        if ((UINT)m_nMaxSize + (UINT)nGrowBy > (UINT)INT_MAX)
            nGrowBy = INT_MAX - m_nMaxSize;

        nNewMaxSize = __max(nNewMaxSize, m_nMaxSize + nGrowBy);

        // Verify that (nNewMaxSize * sizeof(TYPE)) is not greater than UINT_MAX or the realloc will overrun
        if (sizeof(TYPE) > UINT_MAX / (UINT)nNewMaxSize)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        TYPE* pDataNew = (TYPE*)realloc(m_pData, nNewMaxSize * sizeof(TYPE));
        if (pDataNew == NULL)
            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

        m_pData = pDataNew;
        m_nMaxSize = nNewMaxSize;
    }

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::SetSize(int nNewMaxSize)
{
    int nOldSize = m_nSize;

    if (nOldSize > nNewMaxSize)
    {
        assert(m_pData);
        if (m_pData)
        {
            // Removing elements. Call dtor.

            for (int i = nNewMaxSize; i < nOldSize; ++i)
                m_pData[i].~TYPE();
        }
    }

    // Adjust buffer.  Note that there's no need to check for error
    // since if it happens, nOldSize == nNewMaxSize will be true.)
    HRESULT hr = SetSizeInternal(nNewMaxSize);

    if (nOldSize < nNewMaxSize)
    {
        assert(m_pData);
        if (m_pData)
        {
            // Adding elements. Call ctor.

            for (int i = nOldSize; i < nNewMaxSize; ++i)
                ::new (&m_pData[i]) TYPE;
        }
    }

    return hr;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::Add(const TYPE& value)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = SetSizeInternal(m_nSize + 1)))
        return hr;

    assert(m_pData != NULL);

    // Construct the new element
    ::new (&m_pData[m_nSize]) TYPE;

    // Assign
    m_pData[m_nSize] = value;
    ++m_nSize;

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::Insert(int nIndex, const TYPE& value)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Validate index
    if (nIndex < 0 ||
        nIndex > m_nSize)
    {
        assert(false);
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    // Prepare the buffer
    if (FAILED(hr = SetSizeInternal(m_nSize + 1)))
        return hr;

    // Shift the array
    MoveMemory(&m_pData[nIndex + 1], &m_pData[nIndex], sizeof(TYPE)* (m_nSize - nIndex));

    // Construct the new element
    ::new (&m_pData[nIndex]) TYPE;

    // Set the value and increase the size
    m_pData[nIndex] = value;
    ++m_nSize;

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::SetAt(int nIndex, const TYPE& value)
{
    // Validate arguments
    if (nIndex < 0 ||
        nIndex >= m_nSize)
    {
        assert(false);
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    m_pData[nIndex] = value;
    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Searches for the specified value and returns the index of the first occurrence
// within the section of the data array that extends from iStart and contains the 
// specified number of elements. Returns -1 if value is not found within the given 
// section.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> int CGrowableArray <TYPE>::IndexOf(const TYPE& value, int iStart, int nNumElements)
{
    // Validate arguments
    if (iStart < 0 ||
        iStart >= m_nSize ||
        nNumElements < 0 ||
        iStart + nNumElements > m_nSize)
    {
        assert(false);
        return -1;
    }

    // Search
    for (int i = iStart; i < (iStart + nNumElements); i++)
    {
        if (value == m_pData[i])
            return i;
    }

    // Not found
    return -1;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Searches for the specified value and returns the index of the last occurrence
// within the section of the data array that contains the specified number of elements
// and ends at iEnd. Returns -1 if value is not found within the given section.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> int CGrowableArray <TYPE>::LastIndexOf(const TYPE& value, int iEnd, int nNumElements)
{
    // Validate arguments
    if (iEnd < 0 ||
        iEnd >= m_nSize ||
        nNumElements < 0 ||
        iEnd - nNumElements < 0)
    {
        assert(false);
        return -1;
    }

    // Search
    for (int i = iEnd; i >(iEnd - nNumElements); i--)
    {
        if (value == m_pData[i])
            return i;
    }

    // Not found
    return -1;
}



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::Remove(int nIndex)
{
    if (nIndex < 0 ||
        nIndex >= m_nSize)
    {
        assert(false);
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    // Destruct the element to be removed
    m_pData[nIndex].~TYPE();

    // Compact the array and decrease the size
    MoveMemory(&m_pData[nIndex], &m_pData[nIndex + 1], sizeof(TYPE)* (m_nSize - (nIndex + 1)));
    --m_nSize;

    return S_OK;
}
```

The following struct will hold all vertex data

```
typedef struct _VERTEX{
    XMFLOAT3 Position;
    XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
}VERTEX;
```

This function load all data

```
std::ifstream ss(YOURFILENAME);

CGrowableArray<VERTEX>      m_Vertex;
CGrowableArray<UINT>        m_Index;

CGrowableArray <XMFLOAT3> Position;
CGrowableArray <XMFLOAT2> TexCoord;
CGrowableArray <XMFLOAT3> Normal;

char cmd[256] = { 0 };
while (TRUE)
{
    ss >> cmd;
    if (!ss)
        break;

    if (0 == strcmp(cmd, "#"))
    {

    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(cmd, "v"))
    {
        float x, y, z;
        ss >> x >> y >> z;
        Position.Add(XMFLOAT3(x, y, z));
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(cmd, "vt"))
    {
        float u, v, w;
        ss >> u >> v >> w;
        TexCoord.Add(XMFLOAT2(u, v));
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(cmd, "vn"))
    {
        float x, y, z;
        ss >> x >> y >> z;
        Normal.Add(XMFLOAT3(x, y, z));
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp(cmd, "f"))
    {
        UINT Value; VERTEX vertex;
        for (int iFace = 0; iFace < 3; iFace++)
        {
            ss >> Value;
            vertex.Position = Position[Value - 1];
            ss.ignore();

            ss >> Value;
            vertex.TexCoord = TexCoord[Value - 1];
            ss.ignore();

            ss >> Value;

            m_Index.Add(AddVertex(vertex));
        }
    }
    }
```

Now m_Index contain indices and m_Vertex vertices of current object
**NOTE: following code only load object with one mesh only !!**

last code: AddVertex function used in code up there!

```
UINT AddVertex(VERTEX vertex)
{
        for (int a = 0; a < m_Vertex.GetSize(); a++)
    {
        if (VertexEqual(m_Vertex[a], vertex))
            return a;
    }
    m_Vertex.Add(vertex);
    return m_Vertex.GetSize() - 1;
}
```

I hope that this code will help you. If you have any questions write a comment!

Quest

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample **MeshFromOBJ10** in DirectX SDK which was written in DirectX10, take a look at it, and i think it's easily to translate it to DX11 since the API for DX10 and DX11 was almost the same.